# What would be an example of action and parameter in DialogFlow?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to understand how to use Action and parameters in DialogFlow. Is it required to have Action name in DialogFlow? Can we use just parameters and leave Action field blank?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can leave the action field empty but that would result in a bad design for your application.

Let me give you an example on How would use it to map Dialogflow Intents to my class and methods.

Suppose, you have following intents:

- `Get.Transactions`: This intent is suppose to fetch all transactions from the backed app. Let's say it has action name as `all.transactions`.
- `Get.Transactions.Followup.Breakdown`: This intent is a follow-up intent of the first one and it is supposed to breakdown all the transactions based on certain criteria. Let's say it has an action name as `breakdown.transactions`.

Now, these two intents are related and works on the similar dataset to produce different result.

In the first intent, my application fetches all the transactions from the database and presents it to the user. And in the second intent, the same list of transactions are broken down into different sets based on some criteria provided by the user. It would be wise to keep both the functionality enclosed in the same class.

So, I would map both the intents to the same class but invoke different methods based on the actions parameter value. That way my code would look something like:

```
public class Transaction {

    public WebhookResponse performAction(WebhookRequest webhookRequest) {
        String actionName = webhookRequest.getAction();
        switch (actionName) {
            case "all.transactions":
                List<Transaction> transactions = fetchAllTransactions(webhook.getParams("userId"));
                // make response
            break;
            case "breakdown.transactions":
                List<Transaction> transactions = breakdownTransaction(webhook.getParams("userId"), webhook.getParams("breakdownCriteria")));
                // make response
            break;
            default:
                // default response
            break;
        }
        return response;
    }

    private List<Transaction> fetchAllTransactions(int userId) {
        // connect to the database
        // fetch all transactions
        // return the result in a form of list
    }

    private List<Transaction> breakdownTransaction(int userId, String breakdownCriteria) {
        List<Transaction> transactions = fetchAllTransactions(userId);
        // loop transactions
        // breakdown transactions based on some criteria
        // return list of transactions
    }
}
```

This is how you can map two different intents to the same class at your backend.

I have pushed a similar design architecture into git. You can refer the code in the following link: https://github.com/vslala/ChatbotDemo/tree/external_intent_mapping
(Let me know if you have any doubts)

**Note: The example has been given using JAVA language.**

Comment: Could you not simply have used the intent names as opposed to the action names to achieve the same? I think that's what the OP was thinking... me too of course!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can leave it empty if you want. It is only used to identify the action you are doing in each intent.

There is a simple example in the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#actions).